# How to design magnetic driveway alarm system?

Tags: antenna, alarm

I want to design "driveway alarm" which detects when a car passes by. I want to do the detection "magnetically" so it's easy to detect is a car and nto person or some animal. I was thinkin to have a rod like ("wand") "antenna" like they have in commercial driveway alarms. Antenna would have ferrite core and circuitry is maybe LC oscillator which changes frequency when metal comes near to antenna? Would this work or is there better ways of doing it?

Because of the shape of commercial detection "wands" (30-40cm long) I was suspecting they have that kind of antenna inside and that would be a good starting point for own design. They advice wand should be positioned "along driveway". A wand design is practical because it's quite easy to install/move. It would be much harder to dig in some loops under ground.

Comment: I think it is the same system as for traffic lights (at least in Europe) - [induction loops](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Induction_loop) - the coil is feeded with AC. If another coil is placed above, it induces AC voltage in it. If the coil is short cutted, the short circuit of the 2nd coil is transferred to the feeding coil, that acts nearly like a short cicuit - this change of behavior is detected. Of course a car is not a coil, but a huge sheet of metal (a car is more or less such a thing) is like a short circuit O ring - just another kind of short circuited coil.

Comment: @BitLauncher This technology is used in the US as well. It's basically exaclty the same as a metal detector.